# An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to execute `bundle`

```
$ gem install pg -v '1.1.14' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Gem files will remain installed in /home/saishbhende24/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/saishbhende24/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/pg-1.1.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`succeeds before bundling.
In Gemfile:
pg
saishbhende24@DESKTOP-ELUO53H:/mnt/c/saishrails/r5.1`$ gem install pg -v '1.1.14' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pg' (= 1.1.14) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: pg

Output is `rails server`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Coco Windows 10

Comment: Check if you have postgres client installed, I never develop on Windows but this is what required on other platform as `pg` use postgres-client to connect to the postgres-server. Hope it help.

Comment: @Coco how do I check

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed postgres for Windows. There are [official installers here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/). Then try again.

Then, if you still experience problems, try manually installing the `pg` gem first by:

```
bundle install pg
```

If you still have trouble you can also look at running rails, postgres, and all your other dependencies like the rest of your gems, redis, etc., on docker. Running ruby on Windows is a notoriously horrible experience. There's many things which aren't as easy as they are on Linux. Docker can solve a lot of those problems for you if you're still having trouble.

Comment: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. I receive this when I do localhost:3000

Comment: `gem install pg` will work here

Answer (score 1):

```
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
```

Fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and then:

```
bundle install
```

will install gem pg in ubuntu 22.04 LTS.